# Awkward Quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am modelling a vehicle suspension wishbone as simple points and links. 
The wishbone is a triangle of three points - the base two attached to the vehicle and the  apex point attached to the wheel.
I know xy and z coordinates for the two base points, and the z coordinate for the apex.

Applying Pythagoras and solving for either the x or y coordinate of the apex (and choosing the correct root for each) gets me the following two equations of the general form,

$$y=C-\sqrt{x^2(D)+x(E)+F}$$
$$y=G+\sqrt{x^2(H)+x(I)+J}$$
Equating the two gets you,
$$C-\sqrt{x^2(D)+x(E)+F}=G+\sqrt{x^2(H)+x(I)+J}$$

Where the only unknown is x. My method has been:

1. Square both sides
2. Isolate resulting roots
3. Square again
4. Isolate again
5. Square again

Does anyone know of a neater way of addressing this kind of problem.
Thanks
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two squarings should be all you need. You have $C-\sqrt A=G+\sqrt B$. Rewrite as $K=\sqrt A+\sqrt B$ (where $K=C-G$), square to get $K^2=A+B+2\sqrt{AB}$, isolate the square root, and square.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, those substitutions were the ticket. Didn't think to simplify it again like that.